# Insert into a table using multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am new to using SQL Server. I have an assignment, and the lecturer is not showing us how to use the tools he wants the assignment to be completed with.

I am trying to come up with a query that will insert the primary key of 3 dimension tables into as well as trying to insert data from the source data in another table.

The source data is a data set of 10000+ Apps on the Google Play Store.

See below for my table and what I need

`DimContentRating` - there are 6 content ratings

```
ContentRatingID(PK)   Content Rating
---------------       --------------
1                     Everyone
2                     Teen
```

`DimCategory` - there are 34 categories

```
CategoryID(PK)   Category
----------       --------
1                Education
2                Finance
```

`DimInstalls` - there are many ranges of installs

```
InstallID(PK)  Installs
----------     --------
1              10000+
2              100000+
```

`googleplaystore` - the table with the 10000+ records and original data

```
App       Category  Rating  Reviews  Installs  Price  Content_Rating  
---       --------  ------  ------   --------  -----  --------------
GMAT 
Question  Education  4.2     240      10000+    Free    Everyone
Bank

Ace Elite Finance    4.1     2898     100000+   Free    Everyone
```

How I need it to look

AppFact - The table that needs the tables above to be broken down from the above tables and inserted using links from Foreign Keys

```
AppFactID    Category  Rating  Reviews  Installs  Price  Content_Rating  
---------    --------  ------  ------   --------  -----  --------------
1              1        4.2     240       1        Free       1
2              2        4.1     2898       2       Free       1
```

I do apologize for not having a query that I tried writing to get it to work but I have not been shown much at all about SQL Server and so the best I know is general queries. What I do know is I need to use the below as well as possible inner joins?

```
INSERT INTO AppFact(...) 
    SELECT ... 
    FROM ...
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: " I need to use the below as well as possible inner joins?

INSERT INTO AppFact(...) SELECT ... FROM ... "   This appears to be the answer to your question, so what are you really asking?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already create the table `AppFact` with PK `AppFactID`, the query you're looking for is:

```
INSERT INTO AppFact (Category, Rating, Reviews, Installs, Price, Content_Rating)
SELECT c.CategoryID, a.Rating, a.Reviews, i.Installs, a.Price, r.ContentRatingID
FROM googleplaystore a
    INNER JOIN DimContentRating r ON a.Content_Rating = r.Content_Rating
    INNER JOIN DimCategory c ON a.Category = c.Category
    INNER JOIN DimInstalls i ON a.Installs = i.Installs
```

You should take a look to [JOINs in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)